# Column 'orderId' not found. com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: mysql, liferay

Following is a custom SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM EEC_Order 
WHERE DATE(EEC_Order.createDate) = CURDATE() 
    AND EEC_Order.status = ? 
    AND EEC_Order.companyId = ?
```

above sql query working in mysql but not working custom sql login liferay

```
public class OrderFinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<Order> implements OrderFinder    {
    public int getTodayOrderCount(String status,long companyId) {
        Session session = null;
        SQLQuery query = null;
        try {

            String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(GET_TODAY_ORDER_COUNT);          
            session = openSession();            
            query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);            
            query.addEntity("Order", OrderImpl.class);          
            QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);            
            qPos.add(status);
            qPos.add(companyId);            
            Iterator<Long> itr = query.list().iterator();
                if (itr.hasNext()) {
                Long count = itr.next();
                    if (count != null) {                
                     return count.intValue();               
                    }
                }                       
            }               
            catch (Exception e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            finally {               
            closeSession(session);              
            }
        return 0;           
    }
    public static String GET_TODAY_ORDER_COUNT = "getTodayOrderCount";

}
```

Console Exception:

```
04:56:56,520 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-6][JDBCExceptionReporter:76] Column 'orderId' not found.
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:30)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:88)
    at com.esquare.ecommerce.service.persistence.OrderFinderImpl.getTodayOrderCount(OrderFinderImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy426.getTodayOrderCount(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of the following line in your code:

```
query.addEntity("Order", OrderImpl.class);
```

this is used when the sql query returns all columns to construct the `Order` entity, for example to use the above statement the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM EEC_ORDER
```

And since your query is only returning an aggregate function `COUNT` which would return a scalar value, single value and so you can't use the `addEntity` method with your count query.

The `addEntity` method will get the result-set and try to set it in the `Order` entity by setting all the columns one by one, using something like `order.setOrderId(resultSet.getLong("orderId"))` and since your sql query is not returning any `orderId` or other columns this fails and you get the exception as above.

#### So now what to do? Read on for the solution:

To return a scalar of type `long` as you are doing in your query you can use the following instead of the `addEntity` method:

```
query.addScalar("countOfOrder", Type.LONG);
```

where `countOfOrder` is nothing but the alias of `count` in the sql query such as

```
SELECT count(*) as "countOfOrder" FROM EEC_ORDER
```

Comment: thats gr8! can you please mark this as an answer then? Thanks